# What can prevent overriding Access-Control-Allow-Origin in server?

Tags: php, wordpress, cors

I am having an WP site with API and I am calling it with other site. I get this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at www.wpsiteurl.com
>   from origin www.theothersiteurl.com has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple
>   values 'www.theothersiteurl.com, *', but only one is allowed.

I found solutions [here](https://joshpress.net/access-control-headers-for-the-wordpress-rest-api/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/miya0001/d6508b9ba52df5aedc78fca186ff6088?signup=true), which basically introduce adding this to the register function:

```
remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
add_action( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function ($value) {
    $origin = get_http_origin();
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    return $value;
});
```

For me this does not work, since it just returns * or whatever is added as origin and another *. Changing the second argument does not help, it seems like there is wildcard added to the origins after adding this action.

I edited the .htaccess file as was advised in the answers. This worked on other environment, where I was testing the solution. However, on other server it did not - the origin was added to the string of origins just as if it was added with the php.

To me it seems there is something preventing from completely overriding the access-control-allow-origin and forces adding to it.

My questions are:

- What can cause the server not allowing to set one Access-Control-Allow-Origin?
- How do I "override" or clear the Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains you can try this link.

Comment: May be this could help => https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/

Comment: Is there a CDN or proxy server between you and the origin? Also, are you blocking OPTIONS? You need it along with GET.

Comment: @adamrights Blocking OPTIONS? Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

There are more than one way to achieve this with multiple host. One is with .htaccess and the other is with php.

**With .htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(google.com|staging.google.com|development.google.com|otherdomain.example|dev02.otherdomain.example)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
    Header merge Vary Origin
</IfModule>
```

**With PHP:**

```
$origin = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

if ($origin == "http://www.domain1.com"
        || $origin == "http://www.domain2.com"
        || $origin == "http://www.domain3.com") {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $origin");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem, but modifying .htaccess got me closer to the solution. I edited the original question to reflect what I found out.

Comment: This could mean that you're htaccess is not allowed to override on your other server change allowOverride None to allowOverride All in the httpd.conf file of apache let me know if it works. Or your mod_headers is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'www.theothersiteurl.com, *', but only one is allowed.

You have to be very careful to only set this header at one point. This can be done in 3 places:

- Core Apache config
- .htaccess
- PHP

I would recommend doing it inside the core Apache config, due to performance and security reasons.

However if you wish to achieve this using the .htaccess file then make sure nothing is modifying it in PHP and make sure AllowOverride is allowed in the `<VirtualHost>` block.